# Going into partnership on a software project as the lead developer - How to licence the software to the company, licence type?

Tags: licensing

[Note - I asked this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com, but the question was closed as apparently that's not the place to ask it. The community on http://answers.onstartups.com/ do not seem to be the people to help with this either, so I am asking ok Stack Overflow, hopefully the right place!]

I'm, going into partnership on a software project as the lead developer - I want to licence the software to the company, and am wondering what licence types would be applicable here.

Payment for the use of the software is likely to be royalty based, or as a percentage of the client bills.

I don't have any experience of this type of set up commercially. Can anyone advice how I might licence the software and what licence types might be applicable here?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on this - are you looking to get paid by the company you are partnering with or take a cut from their profits for selling your software? will it be hosted or download / distributed? is it open-source?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote an article [about this very subject](http://www.techfounder.net/2010/10/05/software-licenses-for-dummies/) after I got a crash course in software licensing from a copyright attorney as part of preparations for a [current venture](http://binpress.com). You can visit it for more details, but I'll outline the basics here -

- From what I understood from your question, you need to give your partners a **Sublicensable** license. This allows the company to sell your software to their clients. They should be giving their clients a **Personal** license which would allow them to use but not sell the software.
- If you don't want your partners to modify your code, the license should be without the **rights to create derivative works**. If the product is open-source, then you might consider allowing them to give their clients this right.
- You need to specify that commercial use is allowed, and you might want to limit it with some additional terms (such as attribution to you etc.)
- The license should be **non-assignable and non-transferable**, so they can't sell their sublicensable license to anyone else.
- This depends on your agreement with your partners, but possibly the license should be an **exclusive license**. This would prevent you from selling this software to anyone else but this company.

You can check the article I linked to for more details.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive answer. That's given me a few key terms to help me work out how to approach this. To answer your questions above, the system is to be 'software as a service', which makes code distribution issues simpler (since there should not be any). It's not open source. Is there a particular type of attorney that deals with this sort of arrangement?

Comment: Sorry ignore last question - copyright attorney, as I see from your article.

Comment: Yes, a copyright attorney - you should seek someone who specializes in software copyright, as copyright is a very broad field.